# circle overlay does not stretch 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to dynamically populate circles with pictures that upon hover, will display an orange tint. However, I have a strange orange border to the picture. Any ideas on how to 'stretch' the picture to cover the orange color? Thank you in advance! Code below:

HTML code:

```
<div class='overlay'>
    <div class='circle' style='background:url(http://www.bigpicture.in/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/BlackAndWhitePortraitsPhotography26.jpg) 100% no-repeat;background-size:cover'>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.circle {
    float: left;
    background: #d9d6d1;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; 
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s; 
    -o-transition: all 0.5s; 
    transition: all 0.5s; 
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.circle:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}

.overlay {
    float: left;
    background:#fd761f;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpPpD/

Comment: Playing with the CSS in chrome developer tools I can see that the orange circle is not lining up with your picture.

Comment: Changing .circle height and width to 181px seems to fix the issue...don't know why though my CSS is not that good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
.overlay:hover {
    float: left;
    background:#fd761f;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
```

The only things I've changed are adding `:hover` to the `.overlay` class and remove the `margin:5px`

**Note:** The way a image gets rounded and resizes in CSS depends on its original size.

Comment: This works for me! However, there's a strange hover effect after I hover off. The best way I can describe it is like a 'camera flash' after I move my mouse off. Not sure why that happens though.

Comment: The effect you are seeing there is the actual transition you added on `.circle` class. If you want to turn off that effect simply remove the following `-moz-transition: all 0.5s; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; -ms-transition: all 0.5s; -o-transition: all 0.5s; transition: all 0.5s;`. Things should work now.